# How to elegantly map form flat object to complex list object using Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-6.0

I have a flat complex type which I need to map to a complex type within a list. I have achieved it using the below code but it is not elegant. The mapping for each individual item has to be specified explicitly even though the types and names match. I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this without such verbosity and tight coupling?

```cs
using AutoMapper;

MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<FlatObject, MyDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.ListObject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<ListObject> {
        new ListObject {
            DTOCustObject = new DTOCustObject {
                MyString = src.CustType.MyString,
                MyInt = src.CustType.MyInt,
                MyBool = src.CustType.MyBool,
                //Others...
                DTOMyObject = new DTOMyObject {
                    SomeString = src.CustType.MyObject.SomeString
                    //Others...
                }
            }
        }
    }));
});

_config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var flatObject = new FlatObject();
flatObject.CustType.MyString = "ABC123";
flatObject.CustType.MyInt = 12345;
flatObject.CustType.MyBool = true;
flatObject.CustType.MyObject.SomeString = "Some String Content";

IMapper mapper = new Mapper(_config);
var myDTO = mapper.Map<MyDTO>(flatObject);

Console.ReadKey();

//###############
//Entity - Source
//###############
public class FlatObject
{
    public CustType CustType { get; set; } = new CustType();
}

public class CustType
{
    public string? MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; } = new MyObject();
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string? SomeString { get; set; }
}

//#################
//DTO - Destination
//#################
public class MyDTO
{
    public List<ListObject> ListObject { get; set; } = new List<ListObject>();
}

public class ListObject
{
    public DTOCustObject DTOCustObject { get; set; } = new DTOCustObject();
}

public class DTOCustObject
{
    public string? MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public DTOMyObject DTOMyObject { get; set; } = new DTOMyObject();
}

public class DTOMyObject
{
    public string? SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just use interface implementations and pass them into the constructor on the target model. 
Then no need for a framework. 
especially mapping frameworks, they make no sense.
Using a mapping framework, simply means, you don't know how interfaces work, and you should know.

Your flat object, isn't flat, so it is missnamed.
Your listObject, isn't required. You can just add DTOCustObject in a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public List<DTOCustObject> DTOCustObjectList{ get; set; } = new List<DTOCustObject>();
}

public class DTOCustObject
{
    public string? MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public DTOMyObject DTOMyObject { get; set; } = new DTOMyObject();

    public DTOCustObject(ICustObjectMapper mapper){
       MyString = mapper.GetMyString();
       MyInt = mapper.GetMyInt();
       MyBool = mapper.GetMyBool();
       DTOMyObject = mapper.GetDTOMyObject();
    }

}

public class DTOMyObject
{
    public string? SomeString { get; set; }

    public DTOMyObject(IDTOmyObjectMapper mapper)
    {
         SomeString = mapper.GetSomeString();
    }
}
```

Now simply implement the Interfaces and their GetMethods on the source object, in the corresponding classes. And presto. No need for any framework of any kind.

This means, no framework, will try change syntax, and force a rewrite. You aren't locked into keeping it updated, there won't be any dependencies on it, etc.
You are free, and the time it takes you to configure, and annotate the code, is equal to the amount of time it takes you to just write the damn interfaces and implementations.

If your objects are autogenerated, simply use the partial keyword, and make the interface implementations in a partial class. Problem solved.

Something to this effect:

```
public class CustType : ICustObjectMapper 
{
    public string? MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; } = new MyObject();

    string GetMyString(){
         return MyString;
    }

    // etc for the rest of the basic types.

   DTOMyObject GetMyObject(){
      return new DTOMyObject(MyObject)
   } 

}

public class MyObject : IDTOmyObjectMapper 
{
    public string? SomeString { get; set; }

    public string GetSomeString()
    {
         return SomeString;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you don't know how to declare an interface...

```
public interface ICustObjectMapper {
    string GetMyString();
    //etc.

}
```

Now please, for the love of everything on this planet. STOP USING MAPPING FRAMEWORKS IN C#, IT MAKES NO SENSE!

Comment: Thanks for that. Your answer made me look-up automapper vs manual mapping performance. I did not know that automapper was so poor in performance! Gives me something to reflect on about my current implementation.

Comment: AM cam map a million objects in a few hundred milliseconds. That should be fast enough for most people :)

Comment: Frameworks, aren't just about speed. While speed is important, it is also important that your code is maintenance free, and easy to read.

1: using C# syntax, will make the code more readable to a wider variety of coders, you do not need to know the syntax of a specific framework to read the code. 
2: you are not dependent on a framework, or any sub-dependencies the framework has
3.Your syntax is relatively safe. The framework can decide to change it's syntax, and thus you need to redo the implementation.

Comment: 4.  The amount of development time it saves you is minimal at best. compared to just doing it yourself. 
Something like entity framework saves you so much work, that learning the syntax of it, is worth it, simply because of what it offers, but mappers just never do. Because mapping syntax is laughably simple.